# What does $[T]_{\cal BB}$ mean?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, change-of-basis

I have been given a matrix P where the columns represent a basis in B. I have also been given a matrix A which is the standard matrix for T. I am then supposed to calculate the matrix for T relative to the basis B, "i.e calculate $[T]_{\cal BB}$".

I have also been given that $T(x)=Ax$

I am very confused about what this means, honestly, I have no clue whatsoever about where to start. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

/Nick

Comment: begin with an example, at least in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: In this example we have a linear transformation from R^3 to R^3 which is given by T(x)=Ax where A is a 3x3 matrice.

Comment: What is your definition of "the matrix of the linear transformation $T$ with respect to the bases $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B$"?

Comment: @Nickewas ... and this is...

Comment: Do you mean T: R^3 --> R^3?

Comment: I just added a picture to clarify the assignment, I hope it's understandable in spite of it being in Swedish

Comment: You just have to apply $T$ to each of the vectors of $\mathcal B$ and decompose what you get as a sum of the elements of $\mathcal B$. Look at your definitions ....

Comment: Are you asking what the expression $[T]_{\mathcal B\mathcal B}$ denotes, or how to compute the matrix of a transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer:

$[T]_{\mathcal{BB}}=P^{-1}AP$.

### Long answer:

$\Bbb R^3$ is a vector space of finite dimension, so it has a basis. In fact, there exists a *canonical basis*, which we can call $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$. This basis is canonical in the sense that a triple $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\Bbb R^3$ corresponds to the vector $x_1e_1+x_2e_x+x_3e_3$. We represent this vector by
$$\left[\begin{matrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{matrix}\right].$$

However, we can give $\Bbb R^3$ another basis, say
$$\begin{aligned}
f_1&=(1,1,1)\\
f_2&=(1,2,2)\\
f_3&=(-1,-2,-1)
\end{aligned}$$
(by the way, these are the columns of $P$). Then any $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in $\Bbb R^3$ can be written as $\lambda_1f_1+\lambda_2f_2+\lambda_3f_3$ for some $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$, but takes a bit more effort to calculate these coefficients. Let's start with something easier: if we know $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$, then how can we recover $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$? We can remark that if $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)=(1,0,0)$, then $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,1,1)$. Doing the same for $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)=(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$, we find that, for any $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$,
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=P\cdot\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\\\lambda_2\\\lambda_3\end{bmatrix}.$$
We then conclude that
$$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\\\lambda_2\\\lambda_3\end{bmatrix}=P^{-1}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}.$$

Back to the operator $T$. $T:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow\Bbb R^3$ is a linear operator in $\Bbb R^3$, and therefore can be represented by a matrix: however, this representation depends on a *choice of bases*, both for the input and for the output. Its representation in the canonical basis is $A$. We can understand this step by step. Take $x$ a vector in $\Bbb R^3$. We can write it in the canonical basis as $x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3$, which gives us a vector $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. $T(x)$ is also a vector in $\Bbb R^3$, so we can also write it out in the canonical basis. This is where $A$ comes in: **the expression of $T(x)$ in the canonical basis is $A\cdot\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.**

Now, instead of representing $x$ in the canonical basis, and getting an output in the canonical basis, we want to represent $x$ in the basis $\mathcal B$, and get the output also in the basis $\mathcal B$. We are therefore looking for a matrix  $[T]_{\mathcal{BB}}$ that takes as input a vector written in basis $\mathcal B$, i.e. a triple $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$, and returns another triple in the basis $\mathcal B$. But we only have a matrix that takes as input a vector written in the canonical basis, i.e. a triple $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, and likewise returns a triple written in the canonical basis.

How can we go from the canonical basis to $\mathcal B$ and back? you might ask. This is where $P$ comes in. $P$ takes a vector written in the basis $\mathcal B$ and returns a matrix in the canonical basis. Similarly, $P^{-1}$ takes a vector written in the canonical basis and returns a matrix in the basis $\mathcal B$. We now have all the tools required to calculate $[T]_\mathcal{BB}$:
$$[T]_{\mathcal{BB}}=P^{-1}AP.$$
To understand why we multiply in this order, imagine a vector being multiplied on the right:
$$[T]_{\mathcal{BB}}x=P^{-1}APx.$$
$x$ is written in the basis $\mathcal B$. $Px$ transforms this into a vector written in the canonical basis. We can then apply $A$, which gives $APx$. Finally, we want to come back to the basis $\mathcal B$, so we multiply by $P^{-1}$, giving $P^{-1}APx$.

---

I'm not too sure if I explained myself clearly, but I hope it helps you understand changes of bases and matrix representation in general!

Comment: can you give me your opinion about my answer? since I am asking you first, I would give you mine after

Comment: @janmarqz Your answer is correct; it's the same as mine. In terms of explaining the answer, of course you did it much more succinctly than I did, but I think all the information is there. You might want to state clearly that multiplying on the left by $P^{-1}$ gives the coordinates of $v$ in the new basis $\mathcal B$, since you use this fact twice.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The first phrase of my response  does that. Thanks again!

Comment: I will upvote you if you upvote the OP... and my answer... that will be a win-win-win XD

Comment: That's very kind of you, but I'd rather not treat reputation points like currency :)

Comment: I respect  your choice

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that the new components of a vector $v$ are given
by multiplying $P^{-1}v$, it is easy to solve you exercise.

For the linear transformation $T$ you calculate
$Av=APP^{-1}v$ from you can see how the matrix $AP$ relates the old version $Tv$
with the new of $v$, but, to change everything in terms of the new basis you do
$P^{-1}Av=P^{-1}APP^{-1}v$ and associate as 
$$P^{-1}Av=(P^{-1}AP)P^{-1}v$$
where you can see how the new components of $Tv$ are related with the new 
components of $v$ through the multiplication $P^{-1}AP$.